# Удаление и создание файлов локальной бд

Tags: c#, sql, linq2sql

Создается локальная бд

```
        public void CreateDatabase2()
    {
        MyDVDs db = new MyDVDs(@"c:\mydvds.mdf");

        if (db.DatabaseExists())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deleting old database...");
            db.DeleteDatabase();
        }

    }
```

Нужно что бы при отсутствии файлов база создавалась заново. Но когда просто удаляешь файлы то выдает эксепшн вида:
"База данных "c:\mydvds.mdf" уже существует. Выберите другое имя базы данных."
При попытки удалить

```
db.DeleteDatabase();
```

Эксепшн вида: "Не удалось прикрепить базу данных, которой автоматически было присвоено имя, к файлу c:\mydvds.mdf. База данных с таким именем уже существует, указанный файл нельзя открыть, или он находится на общем ресурсе UNC."
Как програмно удалить бд на сервере?
Что то мне подсказывает, что

```
DROP DATABASE NAME
```

вернет мне подобную вещь.

Comment: а [такое решение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5170462/4827341) не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Расширение .mdf - это файлы SQL Server. (не путать с .sdf - SQL Server Compact).
Чтобы удалить файл .mdf, надо отключить базу данных. С помощью sql так:

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'имя_базы_данных'
```